# DFT of the discrete function $f(x,y)=1$

Tags: fourier-transform, image-processing

I want to solve the following question from the Digital Image Processing by Gonzalez and Woods book:

> Show that the DFT of the discrete function $f(x,y)=1$ is:
> $$
> \Im\left\{ 1\right\} =\hat{h}(u,v)=\begin{cases}
> 1 & u=v=0\\
> 0 & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$

What I did is to use the definition:
$$
\hat{h}(u,v)=\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}h(x,y)\exp\left(-2\pi iux\frac{1}{M}\right)\exp\left(-2\pi ivy\frac{1}{N}\right)
$$
We know that $h(x,y)=1$ so we get:
$$
\hat{h}(u,v)=\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}\exp\left(-2\pi iux\frac{1}{M}\right)\exp\left(-2\pi ivy\frac{1}{N}\right)
$$
Now I'm stuck and not sure how to progress from here. Do I need to split into cases? For $u=v=0$? How to continue?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Observe that
$$
\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}a_xb_y=
(\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}a_x)
(\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}b_y)
$$
and
$$
\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\exp(cx)=\frac{\exp(cM)-1}{\exp(c)-1}\quad,\quad \exp(c)\ne 1
$$

Comment: Thank for the comments. You get $\hat{h}(u,v)=\frac{\exp\left(-2\pi iu\right)-1}{\exp\left(-2\pi iu\frac{1}{M}\right)-1}\cdot\frac{\exp\left(-2\pi iv\right)-1}{\exp\left(-2\pi iv\frac{1}{N}\right)-1}$, how do you continue from here?

Comment: BTW, do I have a mistake in my equations? because if $g(u)=\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\exp\left(-2\pi iux\frac{1}{M}\right)$ then we get $g(0)=M$ and so we get $\hat{h}(0,0)=M\cdot N$ and not $1$.

Comment: You should divide the equation for $\hat h(u,v)$ by $MN$ to get rid of it when finding $\hat h(0,0)$. And from what you wrote for $\hat h(u,v)$ in your comment, you should use $\exp(-2\pi i u)=\exp(-2\pi v)=1$ since $u$ and $v$ are integers.